# Glog : configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing

Tags: ios, cocoapods, glog

My question is about how to solve the missing script is too old or missing!!

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c

checking whether build environment is sane... yes

checking for arm-apple-darwin-strip... no

checking for strip... strip

checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d

checking for gawk... no

checking for mawk... no

checking for nawk... no

checking for awk... awk

checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes

checking whether make supports nested variables... yes

checking for arm-apple-darwin-gcc...  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot 

checking whether the C compiler works... no

xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located

xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located

xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located

xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'Path' in SDK 'iphoneos'

/Users/henry/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/GLog/1bdd977745f69be933366dc3ed8fb579-a1d70/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option Try `/Users/henry/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/GLog/1bdd977745f69be933366dc3ed8fb579-a1d70/missing
--help' for more information

configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing

configure: error: in `/Users/henry/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/GLog/1bdd977745f69be933366dc3ed8fb579-a1d70': configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables See `config.log' for more details
```

Answer (score 91):

The Path to *iphoneos* is not set.
Run this on CLI to set it: 
`sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app`

Comment: If you're using beta version of xcode, run this - `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app`

Answer (score 0):

Exporting the path worked for me:

```
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:$PATH"
```